# Azure Active Directory Graph Client 2.0 - Contains Expression

Tags: c#, azure, active-directory, graph-api-explorer

When querying Users etc using the Azure ActiveDirectoryClient it does not seem possible to construct a expression that has the 'Contains' keyword e.g.

activeDirectoryClient.Users.Where(u => u.Surname.Contains(searchString))
.ExecuteAsync()

I can successfully use u.Surname.StartsWith or EndsWith.

Is this supported? If not is there an alternative?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Contains` is generally not supported by the Graph API itself. And there is no alternative. It is strange that `EndsWith` works.

You can find more about supported queries and filters on the following official documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn727074.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. This is not critical functionality but would have been useful. EndsWith is not supported, my mistake.